# TypeScript type arguments in JSX nodes

Tags: generics, typescript, reactjs

Is there any way to specify type arguments for components rendered in JSX?

For example, consider this component:

```
interface SelectorProps<T> {
    selection: T;
    options: T[];
}

class Selector<T> extends React.Component<SelectorProps<T>, {}> {
    // ...
}
```

If I try to render this component in JSX:

```
<Selector selection="a" options={["a", "b", "c"]} />
```

I get these errors:

> TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>
> TS2322: Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.  Type 'string' is not
>   assignable to type 'T'.

I would expect `T` to be inferred as `string` or else some way to specify `T=string` in `<Selector>`. Is there a solution?

The only workaround I have found is to extend the component to eliminate all type arguments:

```
class StringSelector extends Selector<string> { }
```

Comment: Not yet. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6395

Comment: Thanks, seems covered by that issue. Will stick with my `extends` workaround for now.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Generic JSX elements as described in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6395 are now supported - since TypeScript 2.9.

You should now be able to use:

```
 <Selector<string> selection="a" options={["a", "b", "c"]} />
```

See also: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the follow up answer as well

Comment: Jeez! How have I never seen this before. Thanks so much for this. This helps me to clean up my code massively!

Answer (score 2):

```
interface FooProps<T> { foo: T; }
class Foo<T> extends React.Component<FooProps<T>, any> {
  render() {
    return <div>{ JSON.stringify(this.props.foo) }</div>;
  }
}
type FooBar = new () => Foo<{bar: string}>;
const FooBar = Foo as FooBar;

class FooBarContainer extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    return <FooBar foo={{bar: 'works'}} />;
  }
}
```

`FooBarContainer` or `<FooBar foo={{bar: 'works'}} />` should render: `<div>{"bar":"works"}</div>`

Comment: A little hard for me to follow the "foobar" jarble but is this really any different than my workaround using `extends`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Your interface should declare explicitly the types of values it expects. That is the whole point of using typescript. You shouldnt infer anything if you really know what to expect.

```
interface SelectorProps {
    selection: string | number; // This means selection can take in either a string or a number
    options: string[] | number[];
}

class Selector extends React.Component<SelectorProps, {}> {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So how would you make a `Selector` that can select strings, numbers, objects, various other interfaces? That's what type arguments are for, so you don't have to use an ambiguous type like `any`.

Comment: In that case please use union types. Am modifying my answer to show you sample usage @Aaron

Comment: I already have 4 different types and in my app they are actual object interfaces, not primitives. Unions don't make it clear that `selection` is the same type as `options`. It requires you to write assertions in code. It also requires you to know up front all types the component will ever deal with. Type arguments are exactly what I need here but the only issue is JSX doesn't (yet) have a way to pass them.

Comment: Oohh my bad then. Dint have the full context of issue

Answer (score 0):

I have gotton generics working in a component I created at my company, but they way I managed to do it wasn't pretty.

**GenericComponent.tsx:**

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IGenericComponentProps<T, S> {
    propT: T;
    propS: S;
}

interface IGenericComponentState<T, S> {}

export class GenericComponent<T, S> extends React.Component<
    IGenericComponentProps<T, S>,
    IGenericComponentState<T, S>
    > {
    public render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div>Generic component!</div>
        );
    }

}

export default GenericComponent;
```

**GenericComponentImplementation.tsx:**

```
import * as React from "react";

// This is the ugly part
import GenericComponentBase from "./GenericComponent";
// This is where you get to define the generic type arguments
interface StringAndNumberComponentBase { new (): GenericComponentBase<string, number>; };
const StringAndNumberComponent = GenericComponentBase as StringAndNumberComponentBase ;

export default (): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <StringAndNumberComponent
            propT="test"
            propS={2}
            />
    );
};
```

I think I got this information from this github issue at the time:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3960